# Booting the processor on a Xilinx Zynq 7000 before the logic

Tags: xilinx, zynq

I am testing some code on an Xilinx Zynq 7000 and I need to be sure that the processor will boot up before the logic does.  After reading through some of the manual it seems that this may be the standard case for this device, however, I cannot confirm whether this is truly the case.  If it is not the standard for this device how do I ensure that the processor boots?

Comment: How is your FPGA logic design going to 'boot'? What does that mean if the logic is not a processor?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: The processor is a hard core in a Zynq device, completely independent of the programmable logic.

Comment: @DaveTweed I know that, but I don't understand what the OP means by "boot up before the logic does". Before the logic does **what**? Boots? Resets? Configures?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the processor subsystem (PS) boots before the programmable logic (PL) is configured. [Chapter 6 of the Zynq-7000 SoC Technical Reference Manaul](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf#nameddest=xBootAndConfiguration) covers this topic in some detail.

The only way to bypass this sequence is to configure the PL directly through its hardware JTAG interface.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest (in fact standard) solution is to have an 'enable' signal in the logic which stops everything when low.

Then you have a register with this enable signal, which you write high from the CPU.
Thus nothing runs until YOU tell it to.

This also solves the problems if the processor is slow to start.
Nowadays it may take a long time before a processor is ready to interact with the logic. It needs to set up the stack, clear the memory and with everything in C++: run all the constructor code (with the memory allocation that comes with it)

An experienced HDL designer will do this from the start when writing the code and build these features in from the beginning. Here are some example code snippets:

```
...
output user_block_enable,
...
reg [31:0] control_register;
...
assign user_block_enable = control_register[0];

   ...
   if (s_axilite_awvalid & s_axilite_wvalid)   
   begin

      // Write to registers
      case (s_axilite_awaddr)  
      C_ADDR_CONTROL   : control_register  <= axilite_write_data;


module user_block(
   ...
   input user_block_enable,

always @(posedge clk)
begin
   if (user_block_enable)
   begin
      // Do something
      ...
   end
end
```

Comment: This sort of thing has no meaning if the PL hasn't even been configured yet.

Comment: As you can see from Elliot Andersen comment there are multiple (confusing) interpretations of the concept "boot up before the logic does". To me 'boot' is different from 'configuration'.